# jsf page not update

Tags: java, jsf

I am using jsf 2.0 and primefaces ,so here is my problem, when i want to delete
a row in database manually then the row is not updated in my jsf page(even when I refresh the page),

for example:
 I have downloaded file item in my jsf page, it contains two images, so now I can delete one file in my database and refresh my page, but my page shows still two files,even when I perform logout and login again. The file is still there,

It will update only ,when I rebuild the project
   so , please help me
thanking you,
Regards ,
Guruprasad

Comment: I am not using method to delete, I can delete directly in to the databse

Comment: On page refresh/reload are you querying for latest records??

Comment: Query will be run but give the same values

Comment: When your database get updated? when you post? when you refresh? or when you re-login? test it, also set your commandButton ajax=false

Comment: I can use the scope as viewscoped , it can problem for this issue?

Comment: No it is not, previously what scope you were using? code snippet will be useful.

Comment: viewscoped only,  can use

Answer (score 2):

Your ORM (your Object-Relational Mapping framework, like ie: Hibernate or JPA) probably has a cache, and when you do changes in DB manually, you omit your ORM, so your ORM will not know if there was an delete/update/insert, and will give you data from cache.

It will not reload when your rebuild, but when you restart your app.

You should disable the cache in your ORM if you would like to remove something manually. But for production, the cache is good :)

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem is that you are removing the row from the database but you don't refresh the list, so the list shown in the datatable still contains the two rows, so you must after delete from the DB refresh your list again, then refresh the form to see the new list.